# How can I get rid of the "preview" view when I load a question?

Tags: support

Everytime I access Physics SE I get this type of preview window:

[image]

Then I have to click outside the frame to enter the page. How can I get rid of this? Why is this implemented in the first place?

Comment: I don't experience this and from the cropped screenshot I can't exactly tell what this screen is, either. What browser and operating system are you using? [for future reference: posting here is fine, but general technical questions usually get better/faster support at [meta.SE]]

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @ACuriousMind 's comment I was able to figure out this: It is not an implementation of Physics SE: it is the "Reader View" from Safari. It suffices to deactivate this setting in the browser and the preview window will no longer appear.